# Android - Move LinearLayout to position after animation

Tags: android, animation, transform, android-linearlayout, margin

I'm using this animation to animate a LinearLayout, but I just cant get it to move the direction the animation ends...

```
TranslateAnimation intro = new TranslateAnimation( Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.8f );
```

I now have this code to make it go to the right position, but it doesnt work:

```
myLinearLayout.setLayoutAnimationListener(
        new AnimationListener() {public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                float pixelsInDP = (float) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );

                int marginLeft = (int) (41 * pixelsInDP);
                int marginTop = (int) ((letter1+3) * pixelsInDP);

                layoutParams.setMargins( marginLeft, marginTop, 0, 0);

                myLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                myLinearLayout.invalidate();
            }
```

myLinearLayout is the LinearLayout, but for some reason the position of the linearlayout just wont change...
**What am I doing wrong here guys?**

EDIT: After a bit more testing, I found out that the onAnimationEnd event is not being triggered at all... what the...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to change

```
myLinearLayout.setLayoutAnimationListener
```

to

```
intro.setAnimationListener
```

Oh so logical... ah well. Now I just gotta fix those margins :P